# Python XML Element Tree finding the value of an XML tag

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to retrieve the value of a particular xml tag in an XML file. The problem is that it returns a memory address instead of the actual value.

Already tried multiple approaches using other libraries as well. Nothing really yielded the result.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree.parse('C:\\Users\\Sid\\Desktop\\Test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
items = root.find("items")
item= items.find("item")
print(item)
```

Expected was 1 2 3 4. Actual : Memory address.
XML File is :

```
<data>
    <items>
        <item>1</item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>2</item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>3</item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>4</item>
    </items>
</data>
```

Comment: Desired output is 1 2 3 4
Basically - All the numbers in the "Item" tag

Comment: see if the answer posted below helped? if it did, you may accept it by clicking on the tick sign beside it. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

test = '''<data>
    <items>
        <item>1</item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>2</item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>3</item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>4</item>
    </items>
</data>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(test, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all("item")

for d in data:
    print(d.text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Using [XML Element Tree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree.parse('list.txt')
root = tree.getroot()

items = root.findall("items")

for elem in items:
    desired_tag = elem.find("item")
    print(desired_tag.text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
1                
2                
3                
4
```

**EDIT:**

If you want them printed in a line separated by spaces.

```
print(desired_tag.text, "\t", end = "")
```